# Apply .htaccess HeaderName to all lower levels?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using the following .htaccess to spruce up my directory list:

```
Options +Indexes
IndexOptions IgnoreCase FancyIndexing FoldersFirst NameWidth=* DescriptionWidth=* SuppressHTMLPreamble
HeaderName header.html
IndexIgnore header.html footer.html favicon.ico .htaccess .ftpquota .DS_Store icons *.log *,v *,t .??* *~ *#
```

It loads header html which contains:

```
<html><head><title>My Stuff</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background: #eee;
    margin: 33px;
    color: #333;
    }
h1 {
    font: 2.0em Georgia, serif;
    }
h1 a:hover, h1 a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    }
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555;
    }
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #777;
    }
a:hover, a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: maroon;
    }
pre {
    font: 0.9em/1.3em "Courier New", Courier;
    margin: 3px 0;
    color: #777;
    }
pre img {
    display: inline;
    }
img {
    margin: 3px 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body><h1><a href="/test" title="My Atlassian Stuff">My Stuff</a></h1>
```

It looks great when I go to the folder `/test/`. However, when I go to `/test/test2/` it doesn't pick up the previous htaccess, thus showing the boring default style. How can I make it stick/recursive for the lower laying subfolders as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Place a `/` before `header.html` to tell Apache to look to the root everytime.

```
HeaderName /header.html
```

**EDIT:** If your header.html file doesn't exist in the root, change the path to be where you have stored the file.

```
HeaderName /path/to/header.html
```

Comment: A god among men, that's what you are :-) Thanks!

Comment: Note: on our server I had to instead use `HeaderName /~username/header.html` where `username` is my username (that's on Apache 2.4.29). Similarly I had to use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/~username/style.css">` in my header to correctly include my CSS.