# How to add a html header to all html pages of a folder automatically with htaccess?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I tried this

```
Options +Indexes
IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HTMLTable Charset=UTF-8
HeaderName /header.html
ReadmeName /footer.html
IndexIgnore header.html footer.html .htaccess
```

[How To Include a PHP File Site-wide Using .HTACCESS or other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792069/how-to-include-a-php-file-site-wide-using-htaccess-or-other-methods)

[Apply .htaccess HeaderName to all lower levels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604857/apply-htaccess-headername-to-all-lower-levels)

[How To Include a PHP File Site-wide Using .HTACCESS or other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792069/how-to-include-a-php-file-site-wide-using-htaccess-or-other-methods)

It just simply does not do anything. I also followed an old guide to enable Layout Header (something with mod_layout in apache) but it seems it's too old.

The best i managed to do is to show the content of my "header.html" into the directory (which is listed with Option +Indexes)

I am doing all of this in a specific folder .htaccess, not in the root .htaccess
It looks like this :

```
Options +Indexes
```

IndexOptions IgnoreCase FancyIndexing FoldersFirst NameWidth=* DescriptionWidth=* SuppressHTMLPreamble
HeaderName header.html

Please, help

Comment: What are you trying to do specifically? What type of header of your trying to send?

Comment: simply some html, with a link and a little message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing HTTP Headers with a HTML "Header" (meaning the top of the page)

A HTTP header is used to define things like the encoding, content type (eg JSON/XML), not to add HTML to the top of another HTML page.

If you want to add HTML to the top of each page, .htaccess isn't the place to do this - you need to use some kind of scripting/programming language (eg ASP/PHP) to include the files.

Note that none of the three SO questions you link do what you want either:

- [How To Include a PHP File Site-wide Using .HTACCESS or other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792069/how-to-include-a-php-file-site-wide-using-htaccess-or-other-methods) and [How To Include a PHP File Site-wide Using .HTACCESS or other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792069/how-to-include-a-php-file-site-wide-using-htaccess-or-other-methods) both use PHP to include the files (and just use htaccess to tell PHP where to find the files).
- [Apply .htaccess HeaderName to all lower levels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604857/apply-htaccess-headername-to-all-lower-levels) as you discovered, adds the header to the **Apache directory listing** page only, not to every page on your site.

Comment: I have: and none of the three links you provide do what you're asking purely in htaccess, they use PHP. The only one that appears to do what you're asking (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604857/apply-htaccess-headername-to-all-lower-levels) only adds the header to the **Apache directory listing pages**, not to your pages.

Comment: Well I had more links because I checked like 50 pages yesterday but I couldn't link all and it was late. I'm only allowed to put 2 links if I'm right.

Comment: You can't do what you're asking using purely .htaccess and HTML files, so I'm fairly confident that even with 50 pages you don't have one that tells you how to do this... if you do, I suggest you copy it ;-)

Comment: When I used the php method (if you mean using auto_prepend_file and auto_append_file or something of this kind) it didn't work either.

And so it's possible to show html on a directory but not on a html page with htaccess?? looks weird to me
Anyway i'm going to find more links where it's said that it's possible to get more infos (incase i didn't understand well)

Comment: Do you have PHP installed on your server? auto_prepend_file definitely works, so I can only assume you either didn't have PHP installed/configured correctly, or had some other issue (eg with the relative path to the file)

Comment: I have php and I don't remember if I put the right path though
So I have to put  these two lines only in a .htaccess on the right folder with the full path? that's all?

Comment: Yes, noting that it will only add the header/footer to .php files, not .html files. I don't believe the included file has to be a .php file, but I can't promise that

Comment: Yes, I read that thing about only .php files (still didn't work when I tried but I'm going to retry). Just being curious, isn't it possible to make html files work though?

Another guide I read yesterday : http://www.jumpx.com/tutorials/index.php?id=wrapper

Comment: It is, although I'm not sure why you'd want to do that as it's un-necessarily non-standard.

Comment: because I need to rename all .html into .php (and I don't know php really :D so I don't even know if I need to add some <?php ?> inside)

Comment: That's what it says when i go onto the php page :
`Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'header.html' (include_path='header.html') in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: It can't find the file, use the absolute path to the file instead. (I'm not sure exactly how it works, but I don't think a normal relative path works... that's not to say **no** relative path works, just that the "relative" part may use a different base folder to what you're expecting)

Comment: 'header.html' refers to the file at the root (which is here). I also tried by placing it in another folder and putting the complete link "/www/pages/header.html", it shows the same error

I also tried the direct link (with http://www etc)

And in my header.html there is only <p>TEST</p>

:(

Comment: Try naming the file header.php instead, although that shouldn't be the problem. I'm still fairly sure that there's a problem with your file path - unfortunately I don't know enough about the specifics of how this works to tell you exactly what's wrong with the path though: I only know that it exists.

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmm wait, I made it work 50% lol, so yes it's a problem with the path. I put the header.html right in the same folder (because last time it was in the parent directory and didn't work even though the path was right)

So Now it works but on all my HTML files converted to PHP `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and it shows me an error (i guess it's because of <?), is there a way for me to make it work with that line? the error is `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'version' (T_STRING) on line 1`

Comment: (up sorry, I edited my last message but that wasn't wise)

Comment: Ok, I resolved this problem!!
I added this to my folder htaccess `php_value short_open_tag 0`

Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 0):

If someone has the same problem, when you write the full path, /www/pages/header.html is not enough, you must write /home/User/www/pages/header.html (if you're on linux or C://etc... on windows)

Why? because it is shown on several folders (recursively), so the path changes depending on the directory you're in