# How to add html header automatically, in every single html/php pages of the subdomain?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, server, http-headers

I have a subdomain and there are more than 20000 HTML pages. Now manually adding an HTML header on every page is quite impossible. cause it will take a long time but I want to do it in a very short time.

That will be an HTML header which will include an "Order Now" button on every HTML page. How can I do that? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34168004/how-to-add-a-html-header-to-all-html-pages-of-a-folder-automatically-with-htacce ?

Comment: Can you include header names and values in question that you want to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. For Example your page look like**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is Sample page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**2. Your all 20,000 files should be in same directory Example below**

mydirectry/file1.html
mydirectry/file2.html
mydirectry/file3.html

so on

mydirectry/file20000.html

**3. You can use PHP code like below to update all files**

```
$allhtmlfiles = glob("mydirectry/*.html");

foreach($allhtmlfiles as $singlehtmlfile){
    
    $htmlupdatedcontent =   '';
    $html               =   '';
    
    
    $html               =   file_get_content($singlehtmlfile);  
    $htmlupdatedcontent =   str_replace("<!doctype html>",'<?php require_once('myphpfile.php'); ?>'."\n".'<!doctype html>',$html);
    
    file_put_content($singlehtmlfile, $htmlupdatedcontent);

}
```

**4.  you can add button information in this file (myphpfile.php).**